# Hotkey to select text and console.log in new line

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I stumbled across this snippet and it works great: https://gist.github.com/harthur/2951063

The problem is that it breaks syntax when I run the shortcut snippet. It inputs a `console.log()` inline and thus breaks syntax.

For example I want to console log the variable `hello`

```
var hello = 'World';
```

Well, the snippet linked above will turn it into:

```
var console.log(hello) = 'World';
```

That is not the behavior I would want. What I want is:

```
var hello = 'World';
console.log(hello);
```

Now, this looks like a multiple command, and out of the box I don't think ST3 supports multiple commands in keybindings. I've looked into the plugin Chain of Command but haven't had success in getting it to output how I want it to. Any one know of a solution?

Comment: Noteworthy package: [LogMagic](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LogMagic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stay with [Chain of Command](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command) you can just define you keybinding as a sequence of commands.
If you don't know which commands are executed open the console `` ctrl+` `` and write `sublime.log_commands(True)` to show all commands, which are executed.

So how you could archive your behavior:

1. copy the current selected variable
2. goto the end of the line
3. insert the console log snippet in the next line
4. paste the copied variable

```js
{
    "keys": ["super+shift+l"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            ["copy"],
            ["move_to", {"to": "eol"}],
            ["move_to", {"to": "eol"}],
            ["insert_snippet", {"contents": "\nconsole.log(\"$1 = \" + $1);$0"}],
            ["paste"]
        ]
    },
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.js" },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

An alternative would be to write a plugin to create a log command below the current line. A plugin has the advantage of multiple cursor support and not changing the clipboard. Press `Tools >>> New Plugin...` and write:

```py
import itertools
import sublime_plugin

class LogVariableCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        for sel in view.sel():
            if sel.empty():
                continue
            content = view.substr(sel)
            line = view.line(sel)

            # retrieve the current indent
            indent = "".join(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c.isspace(),
                                                 view.substr(line)))

            view.insert(edit, line.end(),
                        "\n{0}console.log(\"{1} = \" + {1})"
                        .format(indent, content))
```

To assign a keybinding use:

```js
{
    "keys": ["super+shift+l"],
    "command": "log_variable"
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think about going to end of line because the issue I was running into was that it kept cutting the current line to go to the next line. Thanks! It works perfectly pairing it with Chain of Command.